# Multiple conditions on same column with propel queries

Tags: symfony, propel

*Im using symfony2.5 with propel 1.5.*

Let's assume my entity is called `Foo` and `Foo` has an attribute `numericalValue`. I want to query the database to only show `Foo`s which have a `numericalValue` between either 5 and 10 or 15 and 20.

The SQL statement would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE
    (numericalValue >= 5 AND numericalValue <= 10)
    OR
    (numericalValue >= 15 AND numericalValue <=  20)
```

I want to represent that with a propel query.

I tried this:

```
$query = FooQuery::create('Foo');
$query->condition("min", "Foo.numericalValue >= :bar1", 5);
$query->condition("max", "Foo.numericalValue <= :bar2", 10);
$query->combine(array("min","max"), "and", "first");

$query->condition("min", "Foo.numericalValue >= :bar3", 15);
$query->condition("max", "Foo.numericalValue <= :bar4", 20);
$query->combine(array("min","max"), "and", "second");


$query->combine(array("first","second"), "OR");
```

Which returns in an exception because the number of arguments doesn't match the number of parameters.

`$query->toString()`:

```
Criteria: SQL (may not be complete):
SELECT FROM `Foo` WHERE 
(    
  (Foo.numericalValue >= :bar1 AND Foo.numericalValue <= :bar2) OR
  (Foo.numericalValue >= :bar3 AND Foo.numericalValue <= :bar4)
)
Params: 
  Foo.numericalValue => 5,
  Foo.numericalValue => 10,
  Foo.numericalValue => 15,
  Foo.numericalValue => 20
```

I would expect `Params: bar1 => 5, bar2 => 10, bar3 => 15, bar4 => 20`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params listed under `Params:` do not reflect the values that will be binded.

It actually worked for me after deleting `die($query->toString());`. I hadn't tried for a while because the listed params were still not matching my expections. But it seems like the exception about number of arguments not matching number of parameters went away at some point.

In short: The code from the question works.